# Are galvanized or stainless machine screws OK to use with field-tapped holes in aluminum castings (outdoors, wet)?

Tags: junction-box, wet, galvanic-corrosion

I'm installing some weatherproof cast aluminum junction boxes outdoors (full rain/sun exposure) for a GEC run, and would like to drill/tap additional holes in them to mount brackets etc. Do I need to worry about corrosion when using galvanized or stainless machine screws in these fresh aluminum threaded holes, given that at least one end of the screw will be exposed on the outside? If so, would anti-seize or even threadlocker prevent it? I would be using 10-32 or 1/4-28 screws which I do not plan to ever need to remove, but never say never.

Additional research info:
(From American Galvanizers Association)
[Corrosion of zinc/galvanized in contact with other metals](https://galvanizeit.org/hot-dip-galvanizing/how-long-does-hdg-last/in-contact-with-other-metals)

> Aluminum
>
> When used in mild-to-moderately corrosive environments and/or
> mild-to-moderate humidity, contact between a galvanized surface and
> aluminum is unlikely to cause substantial incremental corrosion.
> However, under very humid conditions or corrosive environments
> (including atmospheres close to bodies of salt water), these materials
> may require electrical isolation from each other for the structure to
> perform as intended.

> Ratio of areas
>
> Any time a bimetallic assembly contains metal systems that are subject
> to galvanic corrosion, the ratio of the cathodic area to that of the
> anode must be carefully considered. The corrosion current that flows
> between the cathode and anode is independent of area, but the rate of
> penetration at the anode is dependent on the current per unit area,
> that is, current density. Therefore, it is undesirable to have a large
> cathode surface in contact with a small anode surface. The rate of
> penetration from corrosion increases as the ratio of the cathode to
> anode surface area increases.
>
> Dissimilar Metal Corrosion
>
> For example, when using a bare steel plate with a zinc rivet, the
> ratio of the cathode surface area to the anode surface area is large,
> and the rivet will fail rapidly because of accelerated corrosion. When
> combining a zinc plate with a stainless steel rivet, the area ratio
> between the cathode and anode is reversed, and although more surface
> area is affected, the depth of penetration is small; the fastener
> should not fail because of corrosion.

Comment: Since the silicone I have cures producing acetic acid, I thought I'd stay away from that. My default at this point would be to use antiseize.

Comment: There are other commonly available silicone formulations that do not produce acid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't intend to remove it and are mounting aluminium brackets to aluminium boxes, use aluminium blind rivets. seal the drill hole and rivet bore with neutral cure silicone.

If you must use steel fasteners stainless is better than galvanised. Galvanised doesn't last well in contact with
aluminium.

The two metals will be in contact in the threaded portion of the joint. there is no way to prevent that, so the longer you can make the wet path between the two metals the better. eg by using painted, hard anodised, or powder-coated boxes, and sealing inside the joint.

Answer (score 0):

Exposed to the outside, sun, heat rain, cold

Since the objective here is to prevent galvanic corrosion best solution is to use electrical insulation.

Any liquid/ fluid will eventually fail.

Teflon will last forever.

Wrap some teflon tape around the screws and use plastic washers.